# On click sub menu not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I am using `.click` to show sub menu. But when I perform a click on the menu the submenu ie. the second `<li>` wont open. I don't know whats wrong Here is my code on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/xzxLp2o0/).

Now, what I need is: when I click on the menu the sub menu should open and when second one is clicked, it should open, but first child should disappear.

Comment: sorry I really don't understand what you've just wrote

Comment: in your JSfiddle you are using Jquery but itn't include. You set no library ( pure-javascript )

Comment: hey man your structure is totally whack may i provide you with my sample menu and submenu structure as a start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzxLp2o0/7/).

```
$('li ul').hide();

$("#leftmenuidfrmslt li").click(function(e) {
    var submenu = $(this).children("ul");    
    if (!$(submenu).is(":visible")) {
        hideSubMenus();
        submenu.slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        submenu.slideUp("fast");
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').click(function() {
    hideSubMenus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i need can you reduce code line

Comment: when i click on page the sub menu is not closing

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$(function () {
    //Hide all the sub menus
    $('li ul').hide();

    $("#leftmenuidfrmslt li").has("ul").click(function (e) {
        $("#leftmenuidfrmslt li ul:visible").slideUp("fast");
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xzxLp2o0/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
$(function () {    
   $('li ul').hide();

   $("#leftmenuidfrmslt li").has("ul").click(function(e) {
        var submenu = $(this);

        $("#leftmenuidfrmslt li ul:visible").slideUp("fast");

        submenu.children("ul").slideDown("fast");

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ka11aqt/). It's a lot easier to label things with classes to denote their function, and makes for much more re-usable code. So for example:

```
.menu { /* my menu class */ }
.menu-item { /* a class for items in a menu */ }
.submenu { /* a class marking a submenu */ }
```

Then you can have your javascript code operate on those classes, rather than having to have convoluted code that follows hierarchies.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".menu > .menu-item").addClass("block-vertical-center");

    //Vertically center any blocks we are supposed to
    $(".block-vertical-center").wrapInner('<span class="table-span"><span class="table-cell-span"></span></span>');

    //Hide all the sub menus to start with
    $(".submenu").hide();

    $("#leftmenu .menu > .menu-item").on("click",function(e) {
        var submenu = $(e.target).find(".submenu");
        var isVisible = submenu.is(":visible");

        //Hide all the sub menus so we don't have multiples open
        $("#leftmenu .submenu").slideUp("fast");
        if (submenu.length > 0){
            if (!isVisible){
                submenu.slideDown("fast");
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

Also, for your vertical-alignment problem: Don't use line-height to vertically-align the contents of a block item. If your text goes to more than one line, it has issues. Instead, you can define a marker class (I often use "block-vertical-center" or something like that) do something like this:

```
span.table-span {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

span.table-cell-span {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;    
}
```

And then in your javascript, you can do:

```
$(".block-vertical-center").wrapInner('<span class="table-span"><span class="table-cell-span"></span></span>');
```

And then you simply define any block whose contents should be vertically centered that "block-vertical-center" class. What this does, is wrap the contents of your block in an inline-table. the vertical-align properties only really work properly in table cells, so we wrap a table around our content and it will magically vertically align, without having to worry about weird line-spacing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the JS code as below

```
$(function() {
    $("li ul").hide();
    var submenu = $("li ul");

    $("#leftmenuidfrmslt li").on("click", function(e){
        if($(this).children("ul").length){
            submenu.slideUp("fast");
            $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this help!